# Where did the name Kris Kringle come from?

Tags: santa-claus

Kris Kringle is one of the many nicknames attributed to supposedly fictional entity Santa Claus. My question is simple. Where did this name come from? How did it come to exist?

Comment: Sorry, but Santa is a real-world person which means that this question is off-topic. We're only interested in questions about *fantasy*; - [***Are questions about Santa Claus on topic?***](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1018/20774)

Comment: http://mythology.stackexchange.com might work for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an Americanized pronunciation of *Christkindl*, meaning "Christ child" in southern German.  In southern Germany, Austria, and Switzerland, it is conventionally believed that the baby Jesus brings presents, not a Santa Claus or Father Christmas character.  Due to confusion over who was bringing the gifts, the *Kris Kringle* name got attached to Santa in North America.